# multiply numpy 2D with 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new in Python

I have: (which files can be access [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p3oM2QZrIdjiKhzJn95OvvcdZppxU6Ug?usp=sharing) )

64 x 47 array `toeplitz = pd.read_excel ('BT4864.xlsx')`

1 x 47 array `compressed = pd.read_excel ('compressed1.xls')`

which I want to transpose toeplitz variable (data type = float) first then multiply it with compressed variable (data type = complex) and I got an error

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas as pd

compressed = pd.read_excel ('compressed1.xls')
comp_array = np.array(compressed)
np.shape(compressed)

toeplitz = pd.read_excel ('BT4864.xlsx')
toep_array = np.array(toeplitz)

A = toep_array
y = comp_array
r = y
data = 64

transpose = np.transpose(A)
c = np.dot(transpose, r)
absValues = np.abs (c)
l2_r = np.sum(np.power(absValues,2))
sd = l2_r / sqrt (data)
```

is there anything that I missed?

Comment: 1. Please read [mre] 2. Please always post full exceptions, not just the last line. 3. Please post reproducible data - we don't have your files. This can't be reproduced. I am getting a different error with `comp_array = np.zeros((64, 47))` and `toep_array = np.zeros((1, 47))`

Comment: hello I've just added files, please check it out. the reason I didn't post the entire code is because the rest of the code just showing the signal plot which I think it has nothing to do with the error. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your code (which is not reproducible), here is what you probably want

```
comp_array = np.zeros((64, 47),dtype=np.complex)

toep_array = np.zeros((1, 47),dtype=np.complex)


A = toep_array
y = comp_array

c = np.matmul(A, y.T)
```

Comment: the `np.zeros()` function is used to create a matrix full of zeroes, isn't? I already have the data in stated size. I have tried  `np.matmul() ` and it returns the same error

Comment: Hi! I find the main problem all my data is still in string, now I'm trying to convert it:)

Comment: @cntk16 the problem is that the question is not reproducible. Please edit it.